# Code::blocks verbose build

Tags: codeblocks

I want to see the actual commands sent to `g++` during a Code::Blocks build. I want to see exactly what command-line arguments it uses in the compile and link steps, and I don't want to have to poke around in the build settings GUI to do it.

Alternatively, converting the Code::Blocks project to an equivalent Makefile would work, but I see nowhere where I can do that, either...

---

### Edit

I ended up using a Code::Blocks plugin, "cbMakeGen", to generate a makefile from which I removed some `@`s. Then I was able to see the commands. Surely there is an easier way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you already solved the problem, but there's still a bit more to that.

Code::Blocks can write a build log when the following option is checked:
Settings->Compiler and debugger->Global compiler settings->{slide tabs to the right}->Build options tab->Save build log to HTML.

Besides, you can use "[cbp2make](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cbp2make/)" to convert Code::Blocks projects to makefiles. This is not a plugin like "cbMakeGen", but a stand-alone command-line tool. See also http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,13675.0.html .

Answer (score 1):

Besides the logging to html you can also go to
Settings->Compiler and debugger->Global compiler settings->{slide tabs to the right}->Other Settings and in that tab set 'Compiler Logging:' to 'full command line' (from drop down menu).

Now you can see the gcc command line in the console when you build.